# Id diferentes para inputs insertados en un table datatables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datatable

Deseo que cada input tenga un id distintos ya que estoy haciendo una compra y al poner una cantidad en algun input esa cantidad se pone para todos.

```
let table_addCardShop = $("#t_addCardShop").DataTable({
  destroy: true,
  dom: '<"top"f>t<"bottom"p><"clear">',
  ajax: {
    url: "src/sql_consult/crud_supplies.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { option: option },
    dataSrc: "",
  },

  language: { url: "src/datatables/spanish.json" },
  columns: [
    { data: "idInsumos" },
    { data: "nombre" },
    { data: "descripcion" },
    {
      data: null,
      render: function (data) {
        
        return "<input class='form-control w-50' id = 'cantAdd'  onkeypress='return soloNumeros(event)' >";
      },
    },
    { data: "precioUnitario" },
    {
      defaultContent:
        "<button  type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm addCardShop mx-5' title='Agregar'><i class='fa-solid fa-cart-shopping'></i></button>",
    },
  ],
});
```

quiero que el id de ese input 'cantAdd' se incremente a 'cantAdd'+n para que sean diferentes al momento de escoger el valor.

```javascript
$(document).on("click", ".addCardShop", function() {
  row = $(this).closest("tr"); //devuelve el antepasado
  id = parseInt(row.find("td:eq(0)").text()); //busca un descendiente

  var nomProd = row.find("td:eq(1)").text();
  var descriptionProd = row.find("td:eq(2)").text();
  var cantProd = $("#cantAdd").val();
  var costo = row.find("td:eq(4)").text();
  var total = cantProd * costo;

  if (cantProd == "") {
    $.toast({
      heading: 'Warning',
      text: 'Ingrese la cantidad!',
      showHideTransition: 'plain',
      position: 'top-right',
      icon: 'warning'
    })
    return;
  }

  var contentTable = `
    <tr>
      <td>${id}</td>
      <td>${nomProd}</td>
      <td>${descriptionProd}</td>
      <td>${cantProd}</td>
      <td>${costo}</td>
      <td id='costoProd'>${total}</td>
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger deleteCardShop"><i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i></button></td>
    </tr>`;
  var contentTfoot = `
    <tr>
        <td>222</td>
    </tr>`;

  $("#tbody").append(contentTable);
})
```

Ahora necesito que el en la variable `var cantProd = $("#cantAdd").val();`, se ponga el valor dependiendo de a que input le inserte un numero ya que si pongo un valor en el primer input este se repite para todos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image]

Comment: Imáginate que lo consigues... es decir, que ahora tienes id llamados **cantAdd1**, **cantAdd2**, **cantAdd3**, etc... Y que luego, cambiando esa asignación a esta puedes recuperar ese valor para hacer los cálculos: `var cantProd = $("#cantAdd" + id).val();`... ¿de que te sirve después al enviar el formulario?  ¿como vas a tratar esos **cantAdd+id** en otra parte si ni tan siquiera estás usando un atributo **name=** para asignarlos correctamente en un formulario?  y aunque lo hicieras... ¿vas a basar la recepción de ese dato partiendo la cadena para recuperar el id?... no se, lo veo liado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pesar de lo dicho en los comentarios, lo que inicialmente pretendes creo que lo puedes lograr haciendo estos pasos:

1. Cambia esta línea:

```javascript
return "<input class='form-control w-50' id = 'cantAdd'  onkeypress='return soloNumeros(event)' >";
```

por esta otra:

```javascript
return "<input class='form-control w-50' id = 'cantAdd_" + data.idInsumos + "'  onkeypress='return soloNumeros(event)' >";
```

pues **data** nos apunta a la fila actual y tiene como propiedades las columnas.

2. Y luego cambia esta:

```javascript
var cantProd = $("#cantAdd").val();
```

por esta:

```javascript
var cantProd = $("#cantAdd_" + id).val();
```

porque **id** ya lo asignas antes al valor de la primera columna.

Pruébalo y ya nos diras si te funciona.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me funciono increiblemente. Eres dios, lo que pasa es que no soy muy bueno usando datatables y no conozco muy bien como mezclarlo con JS solo se lo basico, muchas gracias por ayudarme. Solo un detalle como tal 'row.idInsumos ' lo reemplace con 'data.idInsumos ' y listo.